Jaspersoft Studio Gives Compilation Errors for 'switch' Syntax, Even It Uses Java 17
I'm Using Jaspersoft Studio 7.0.1 and trying to implement a Java 'switch' statement for a text field and getting 'Switch Expressions are supported from Java 14 onwards only' error when compiling it. I have tried build path configurations and compilation settings, but nothing worked. I'm using a Windows 11 machine(Java 17.0.4.1 already installed in it) and using the same java bin path for the Japer SDK as well. Anyone has a solution for this please?




